# Wordpress redirects to localhost

Tags: php, permalinks

I have this wordpress website hosted on a subdomain, the url of the homepage is fine, but all other subpages are redirecting to "localhost/pageName", I already : 
• Updated the wp-config with define() function,
• Updated the wp_option table on the DB,
• Updated the permalinks,
• Updated the function.php with update_option(),
• Updated The “Site Address (URL)” and the “WordPress Address (URL)” setting

But after all this, the subpages are still redirecting to the localhost.
If anyone can help. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try a search and replace on the database? The plugin "Better Search Replace" is a good option if you don't want to deal with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks Michelle, already done this, there is no reference to localhost in the all the DB. I download my db (*.sql) and open it with a text editor and search what ever i need, very simple trick.